# How to use ActionBarActivity in context of NavigatorActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, uinavigationbar, contextual-action-bar

I'm attempting to adapt [Google's sample app code for a Navigation Drawer activity](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) to my own app, but the activity I want to replace the fragment portion with is an `ActionBarActivity`. I need to be able to work with a unique action bar in each (fragment), navigated with the drawer overall. I've researched and found that although `ActionBarActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`, trying to code `Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();` is a big no-no. Please excuse my naivety if that code seems ridiculous, which I'm aware it might.

**EDIT:** I am now realizing that a FragmentActivity is not what I am seeking for, but rather a Fragment.

Basically I don't understand how to adapt:

```
Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

to allow me to use my pre-coded `ActionBarActivity` as the fragment. Thanks!

**EDIT:** I'm starting to see that the `NavigatorActivity` itself extends `ActionBarActivity` and one can likely change the action bar according to whichever fragment is being shown. I still don't quite understand how the action bar can have the same/different buttons and function differently with each respective fragment, however.

Comment: A `FragmentActivity` is not a `Fragment`, you cannot use an activity in place of a fragment. What exactly do you need to be unique about the action bar for each fragment? It can probably be implemented by overriding the various `OptionsMenu` methods.

Comment: You might be looking for [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html).

Answer (score 0):

Set up the navigation drawer normaly. if you want a new actionbar in every fragment just call

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragmentTwo, menu);  
}
```

Making this in every fragment will give you new possibilities. If you want to persolize it do it onCreate();

Ps:I see that you are bit confuse how NavigationDrawer works. Just create a ActionBarActivity that expands an NavigationDrawer and on each click on the NavigationDrawer it retrieves a fragment. It is really simple to use it.

If using Android Studio go to the File/Import Sample and choose the NavigationDrawer sample it will help you understand it.